# Join on the same table from two different sources

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 tables: person, image and comment. Person has fields id and name. Images are for a specific person so it has id, person_id, image_name. And comment is kind of a hybrid table because a comment can be either directly for a person or for an imaga - so it has fields id, person_id, image_id and comment.

The same table was used for both comments because the comment plugin is identical for both cases and i also need to show all comments in a live feed so it seemed easier to keep them in one table.

My problem now is tho how can i write a query that gives me all the relevant data reardless if comment is for person or for image.

Select should return a row for each comment with additional data:
comment
image_name (if comment is tied to image_id)
person_name (regardless if comment is tied directly to person or to an image)

The problem im facing is I don't really know how to select person through image if image_id is present and otherwise select person directly through person_id. Also its kind of hard to search for this kind of a solution because its hard to put it in words.

Edit, added sqlfiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7fa06a/1

The thing that is currently missing is the person data for second row. That data should be available because image table has person_id but i dont know how to select it.

Comment: It would help if you'd include sample data from each table, the output you're trying to obtain from that data, and show your effort to solve this yourself. Can you [edit] your post to include that information?

Comment: edited the main post and added sqlfiddle

Answer (score 2):

Solution seemed to be to join person table with both person and image using OR and depending which one is present it gets joined:

```
SELECT * 
FROM comment 
LEFT JOIN image ON image.id = comment.image_id
LEFT JOIN person ON person.id = image.person_id OR
          person.id = comment.person_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do that with `COALESCE()`. It returns the first argument that is not `NULL`.

```
SELECT comment.comment, image.name, COALESCE(person.name, image_person.name)
FROM comment
LEFT JOIN person on person.id = comment.person_id
LEFT JOIN image ON image.id = comment.image_id
LEFT JOIN person image_person ON image_person.id = image.person_id
```

The answer of user1985273 should more efficient, though.

Comment: not quite what im looking for, edited the main post and added sqlfiddle

Comment: I think I got it now. I fixed the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make comment table as main table and then left join person and image tables.

```
Select *  from comment c left join person p on p.id=c.person_id left join image i on i.image_id=i.id and i.person_id=c person_id
```

Comment: not quite what im looking for, edited the main post and added sqlfiddle